# How to Separate NEO4J db Connection in Asp.net Core?

Tags: c#, neo4j, asp.net-core, cypher

in NEO4J driver for .net to run queries we should use below code

```
using (var driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "neo4j")))
        using (var session = driver.Session()){
{
 var statementTemplate = "Match (n:Test {Id:{Id}}) Return n.Name as test";
 var statementParameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Id", "121" } };
 var statementResult = session.Run(statementTemplate, statementParameters);
 Console.WriteLine(record["test"].As<string>());
}
```

now i want to have that code in another class an when i want to run queries just call that class and run my query

Comment: any body help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put `GraphDatabase.Driver` in a new method and call the method in startup constructor